# JSON parsing using Jettison

Tags: java, json, jettison

I am trying to parse JSON object using Jettison.
This the code I'm using

```
String s ="{\"appUsage\":[{\"appName\":\"ANDROID\",\"totalUsers\":\"0\"},{\"appName\":\"IOS\",\"totalUsers\":\"4\"}]}";

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

ArrayList<MiAppUsage> l1 =  (ArrayList<MiAppUsage>) jsonParser(ArrayList.class, obj);

public static Object jsonParser(Class c, JSONObject obj)
            throws JSONException, XMLStreamException, JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(c);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        MappedNamespaceConvention con = new MappedNamespaceConvention(config);
        XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(obj, con);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        ArrayList<MiAppUsage>customer = (ArrayList<MiAppUsage>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader);
        return customer;
    }
```

I'm getting this error

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"appUsage"). Expected elements are
>   (none)]   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.json.UnmarshalDemo.jsonParser(UnmarshalDemo.java:56)
>     at com.json.UnmarshalDemo.main(UnmarshalDemo.java:33) Caused by:
>   javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"",
>   local:"appUsage"). Expected elements are (none)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 4 more Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
>   unexpected element (uri:"", local:"appUsage"). Expected elements are
>   (none)    ... 14 more

How to resolve this problem

Comment: What does your JAXB-annotated model look like?

Answer (score 5):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

If you are ultimately looking for a way to interact with JSON using a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation, then the following is how it can be done using MOXy.  Jettison is an interesting library but there are some issue you will encounter using it:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html

**Demo**

Only the standard Java SE APIs are used.  There are two MOXy specific properties that need to be set on the `Unmarshaller`:  `"eclipselink.media-type"` to specify `"application/json"`, and `"eclipselink.json.include-root"` to indicate that there is no root node.

```
package forum9924567;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    private static final String s ="{\"appUsage\":[{\"appName\":\"ANDROID\",\"totalUsers\":\"0\"},{\"appName\":\"IOS\",\"totalUsers\":\"4\"}]}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource(new StringReader(s));
        Root root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Root.class).getValue();

        ArrayList<MiAppUsage> customer = root.appUsage;
        for(MiAppUsage miAppUsage : customer) {
            System.out.print(miAppUsage.appName);
            System.out.print(' ');
            System.out.println(miAppUsage.totalUsers);
        }
    }

}
```

**Root**

I had to introduce this class to meet your use case.  We could eliminate this class if your JSON looked like:  `[{"appName":"ANDROID","totalUsers":"0"},{"appName":"IOS","totalUsers":"4"}]`.

```
package forum9924567;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    ArrayList<MiAppUsage> appUsage;

}
```

**MiAppUsage**

```
package forum9924567;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MiAppUsage {

    String appName;
    int totalUsers;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `java.properties` with the following entry in the same package as your domain classes:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Output**

The following is the output from running the demo code:

```
ANDROID 0
IOS 4
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Coming back to OP's original question, how do we solve this problem using Jettison?

Answer (score 1):

I think this cannot be done with Jettison. Seems like the `JSONObject` does not like the root element having an array as its value. If it's an option, you may change your input into a JSON array, which can be parsed with Jettison:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String s ="[{\"appUsage\":{\"appName\":\"ANDROID\",\"totalUsers\":\"0\"}},{\"appUsage\":{\"appName\":\"IOS\",\"totalUsers\":\"4\"}}]";

  JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(s);

  List<MiAppUsage> list = unmarshal(MiAppUsage.class, arr);
  for(MiAppUsage miAppUsage : list) {
    System.out.println(miAppUsage.appName + ": " + miAppUsage.totalUsers);
  }
}

public static <T> List<T> unmarshal(Class<T> cls, JSONArray arr) throws JSONException, XMLStreamException, JAXBException {
  List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    list.add(unmarshal(cls, arr.getJSONObject(i)));
  }
  return list;
}

public static <T> T unmarshal(Class<T> cls, JSONObject obj) throws JSONException, XMLStreamException, JAXBException {
  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(cls);
  Configuration config = new Configuration();
  MappedNamespaceConvention con = new MappedNamespaceConvention(config);
  XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(obj, con);

  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
  return cls.cast(unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader));
}
```

This prints:

```
ANDROID: 0
IOS: 4
```

The JAXB-annotated model class is like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "appUsage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MiAppUsage {
  String appName;
  int totalUsers;
}
```

As an alternative to Jettison, your original JSON input can be easily parsed with [StAXON](https://github.com/beckchr)'s `JsonXMLMapper`, which works with any JAXB implementation:

```
String s ="{\"appUsage\":[{\"appName\":\"ANDROID\",\"totalUsers\":\"0\"},{\"appName\":\"IOS\",\"totalUsers\":\"4\"}]}";

JsonXMLMapper<MiAppUsage> mapper = new JsonXMLMapper<MiAppUsage>(MiAppUsage.class);
List<MiAppUsage> list = mapper.readArray(new StringReader(s));

for(MiAppUsage miAppUsage : list) {
  System.out.println(miAppUsage.appName + ": " + miAppUsage.totalUsers);
}
```

For more information on StAXON's JAXB support, refer to the [Using JAXB](https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/wiki/Using-JAXB) wiki page.

Comment: Coming back to OP's original question, how do we solve this problem using Jettison?

Comment: Jettison seems to have a problem here. I edited my answer and added a solution using Jettison with a slightly modified input.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your class MiAppUsage with 
@XmlRootElement(name = "appUsage", namespace="")

eg:- 
@XmlRootElement(name = "appUsage", namespace="")
public class MiAppUsage {

}